# How to better organize consecutive replace methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, replace, mootools

I have a sequence of replace methods, including regular expressions. They are all put together like this:

```
motivation = motivation.replace('death','life').replace('sad','happy').replace(/fu+ck/gi,'yay!').replace('darkness','light');
```

Is there a way to organize this to be more readable? Not having to repeat "replace" all the time would be a good start. I also have access to the Mootools library.

Comment: That's already quite readable IMHO, and you can add split the lines and stack the calls to `replace()` under one another if you want to further increase readability. Writing a helper function that takes a hash like `{ "pattern": "replacement" }` wouldn't work since the order of the calls matter. Having that function take an array of `{ pattern: "death", replacement: "life" }` objects would result in longer and slower code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the simplest thing I can think of: clever indentation.

```
motivation = motivation.replace('death','life')
   .replace('sad','happy')
   .replace(/fu+ck/gi,'yay!')
   .replace('darkness','light');
```

Another option is just to use something like `Array.each` (I think that's in Mootools):

```
Array.each([['death', 'life'],['sad', 'happy'],[/fu+ck/gi, 'yay!'],
            ['darkness', 'light']],
    function (pair) { motivation = motivation.replace(pair[0], pair[1]); });
```

This only really makes sense for very long lists of replacements.

Comment: Modern JavaScript has `Array.map()` but I'm not sure if that's something to rely on.

Comment: Actually, thinking about modern JavaScript, you could also write this neatly as a reduce. Using map feels like the semantics are wrong--map is supposed to return a value instead of doing a bunch of side-effects. In general, my advice in situations like this is to use underscore.js, but I doubt the OP wants to introduce another dependency.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the side-effects, it *is* semantically wrong.

Comment: @tinkon jelvis how would _.js help here, it's not as if it has array methods mootools does not

Comment: @Tikhon Jelvis, thank you. My list of replacements is actually very long (and dirty since I used some complex regexes), so it's not exactly as readable as the example I gave. This is for a personal hobby, so I wouldn't mind adding other dependency, but the Mootools code you provided works perfectly. From what I see it is basically the same as the other answers - but using the Mootools built-in function instead of writting it from scratch.

Comment: @screener: Given a very long list, you should consider defining it in its own variable and perhaps indenting it with one or two pairs per line to make it more readable. Also, since you're doing this as a personal hobby, you should definitely at least look at underscore.js--it's a very neat and minimal library of utility functions like `_.each` and `_.map`, as well as a ton of others, that are *really* useful and can make your code both more readable and concise.

Answer (score 1):

You could add line-breaks.

```
motivation = motivation
             .replace('death','life')
             .replace('sad','happy')
             .replace(/fu+ck/gi,'yay!')
             .replace('darkness','light');
```

Other than that - unless you change the entire approach - no, I don't see how to improve it.

Changing the approach could mean something like this:

```
function replaceMany(s /*, [search, replace], ... */) {
  for (var i=1, l=arguments.length; i<l; i++) {
    s = s.replace(arguments[i][0], arguments[i][1]); 
  }
  return s;
}
```

Then you could call it as:

```
var motivation = replaceMany(
  motivation, 
  ['death','life'], ['sad','happy'], [/fu+ck/gi,'yay!'], ['darkness','light']
);
```

The advantage of wrapping it in a function is clearly that you can change *what's being replaced* without changing your source code. So unless you have a fixed, limited set of replacements that will never change, the latter approach is the better one.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I believed that I couldn't add line-breaks between each `.replace`, but all functions and examples that you provided were even better. I had tried to write a function like yours, but I didn't know how to deal with the two-dimensional array.

Comment: @screener: JavaScript statements end with a `;`, not with a newline. Feel free to format your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the original unreadable, especially not if you add in some line breaks as suggested by the other answers. So I'd do exactly what Tomalak and Tikhon said.

But if you really want to avoid repeating `.replace` all the time you could create a function that takes in an array of find/replace text:

```
function replaceMany(str, replacements) {
   for (var i=0; i<replacements.length; i+++)
      str = str.replace(replacements[i][0], replacements[i][1]);
   return str;
}

motivation = replaceMany(motivation, [ ['death','life'],
                                       ['sad','happy'],
                                       [/fu+ck/gi,'yay!'],
                                       ['darkness','light'] ]);
```

Obviously I've chosen to make the `replacements` parameter an array where each element is a two-element array with the text to find (or regex) and the corresponding replacement text.

I don't really recommend messing with built-in object prototypes, but if you're someone who does then:

```
String.prototype.replaceMany = function(replacements) {
   var str = this;
   for (var i=0; i<replacements.length; i+++)
      str = str.replace(replacements[i][0], replacements[i][1]);
   return str;
}

motivations = motivations.replaceMany([/*array as above*/]);
```